# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component. in react native project

Tags: react-native, visual-studio, android-studio

I am making a project in react native and its showing, again and again, this error:

I am only working on 3 files and I don't know where its issue is coming.

I am sending you the code of 3 files of code below please check them and let me know.

1. **App.js**

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-web';
import SignInScreen from './src/screen/SignInScreen';
const App = () => {
  return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.root}>
      <SignInScreen />   
     </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  }
})
export default App
```

2. **SignInScreen.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
const SignInScreen =  () => {
    return (
      <text>Sign In Screen</text>
    )
}

export default SignInScreen
```

3. **index.js**

```js
export {default} from "./SignInScreen";
```

Comment: it should be <Text> instead of <text>

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering text as `<text> Your text </text>`

But

You have to render as `<Text> Your Text </Text>`

Comment: thanks for it solved but now showing the error:     Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `div` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot my problem is solved great help.

Comment: This comment is not the answer to the question, rather a response. Consider adding such statements in the comment section of the actual answer.